# jquery autocomplete php error 404

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

as some other peoples, i'm having problems with jquery's autocomplete and mysql.
i always get a 404 and don't know why.

that's what the autocomplete is connected to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#planeID-input').autocomplete({source:'suggest_planeID.php', minLength:1});    
});
```

and here is my suggest_planeID.php looks like:

```
<?php
include "db_connect.php";
$search = protect($_GET['term']);   

$result = mysql_query("SELECT planeID FROM `planes` WHERE `planeID` LIKE '%$search%' ")     or die('Something went wrong');

$json = '[';
    $first = true;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        if (!$first) { $json .=  ','; } else { $first = false; }
        $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['planeID'].'"}';
    }
    $json .= ']';
echo $json;
```

The  error i get in Chrome console is:

```
GET http://localhost/phptomysql/try_2/suggest_planeID.php?term=D-0 404 (Not Found)
```

Some ideas or hints?

Comment: Check if the path `http://localhost/phptomysql/try_2/suggest_planeID.php` leads to the correct directory and is available for the webserver.

Comment: great! never considered such a dumb mistake as reason :)

but now i have the problem that no result is returned from the database although i try values that actually exist within the DB.

i have no idea how to debug this.

Comment: mysql looks like:

i have ha DatatBase called "test" with a table caled "planes" inside. This table has two columns 'planeID' and 'planeType"

Comment: It might be best to post this as a new question. I'll add my comment as answer to your initial question, feel free to accept it.

Comment: thank you @Bjoern. you can find it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260932/jquery-autocomplete-with-php-file-that-queries-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the path `http://localhost/phptomysql/try_2/suggest_planeID.php` leads to the correct directory and is available for the webserver.