# jquery autocomplete with php file that queries a mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i'm trying to use a jquery autocomplete text-input with a mysql database for autocomplete suggestions. From a tutorial i got the following php function that is used to query a database.

```
<?php
include "db_connect.php";
$search = protect($_GET['term']);   

$result = mysql_query("SELECT planeID FROM `planes` WHERE `planeID` LIKE '%$search%'     ")     
or die('Something went wrong');

$json = '[';
$first = true;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if (!$first) { $json .=  ','; } else { $first = false; }
    $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['planeID'].'"}';
}
$json .= ']';
echo $json;
```

within the chrome networkpanel, i can see, that after each input into my textfield a request to "suggest_planeID.php?term=d-" i sent but i don't reveive any suggestion.

the database looks like this:
i have ha DatatBase called "test" with a table caled "planes" inside. This table has two columns 'planeID' and 'planeType".

is there any chance to debug the php file to find the error or does anyone here already see the error?

Comment: what is that protect function? Are you receiving any errors in the server web logs?

Comment: as far as i can see, it stores injected searchstring for later use within the mysql_query

Comment: what do the planeIDs look like?

Comment: i was able to identify the problem by call the address that is send "http://localhost/phptomysql/try_2/ajax/suggest_planeID.php?term=D" manually in my browser. so i retreived an error message that the path to my db_connect.php script is wrong. easy to fix.. :)

Comment: Sideways of the problem, you could (and should) use `json_encode()` to create `json` data.